# How to pass non-latin string to url parameter in django?

Tags: django, unicode, python-unicode

Using django 1.7 and python 2.7, in a views I have:

```
page = 0
sex = [u'\u0632\u0646'] #sex = زن
url = "/result/%s/%d"  % (sex, page)
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Which needs to return:

```
/result/زن/0
```

However the resulting url turns out to be:

```
/result/[u'\u0632\u0646']/0
```

Which is not what envisage in the pattern:

```
`url(r'^result/(?P<sex>\w+)/(?P<page>\d+)','userprofile.views.profile_search_result')`,
```

I also tried

```
return HttpResponseRedirect( iri_to_uri(url))
```

but does not solve the problem.

I got really confused and appreciate your help to fix this.

Comment: But seems that  `sex` is the second part of your pattern `r'^result/(?P<sex>\w+)/(?P<page>\d+)'`? And about your `url` you need to specify for python that the format is unicode you you need to add a `u` at the leading of your url `url = u"/result/%s/%d"  % (sex, page)`

Comment: or in return use `unicode` function `return HttpResponseRedirect(unicode(url,'escape-unicode'))`

Comment: @Kasra, the intended first parameter after `/result` is `زن` as is evident in url pattern. However browser (and text editor here) moves `0` to the left of `زن` (not sure why).

Comment: @Kasra `return HttpResponseRedirect(unicode(url,'escape-unicode'))` causes: `decoding Unicode is not supported`

Comment: Yes it could be done , although my consul show it right `>>> print url
/result/زن/0 ` . :) sorry decoding is `'unicode-escape'`! but i think this could be relevant to your browser too! for more detail check this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/unicode/#uri-and-iri-handling

Comment: Your claimed result is *not* what you get when you run that code. The code runs perfectly and gives the expected result: `/result/زن/0`. You would only get the result that you show if `sex` is a list.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right. the sex was indeed a list: `[u'\u0632\u0646']` . I modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sex is a list, you simply need to use the actual element you want:

```
url = "/result/%s/%d"  % (sex[0], page)
```

Although note that to construct URLs in Django, you should really use the `reverse` function:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
...
url = reverse('userprofile.views.profile_search_result', kwargs={'sex': sex[0], 'page': page})
```

Answer (score 1):

`url` should also be an unicode string for that to work:

```
page = 0
sex = u'\u0632\u0646' #sex=زن
url = u"/result/%s/%d"  % (sex, page)
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: Also you need to mention that what OP wants to return doesn't  meed his condition on the regex pattern !

Comment: This yeilds to another weird url i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/[u'%5Cu0632%5Cu0646']/0`